# "Stack Exchange requires external JavaScript from another domain" error

Tags: support

I have to say that Stack Exchange website is a good one. However, for quite a long time I can not leave any messages on it and when I open the page.

I just saw 'Stack Exchange requires external JavaScript from another domain, which is blocked or failed to load'.

I just wanna know what the problem with the Stack Exchange network or something with my computer?  How to deal with this situation?

Comment: Given that you have successfully posted a message now, does that help you find the problem? What was different this time? Different browser? AdBlock disabled? anti-virus updated? firewall rules changed? ghostery config changed? any one of a hundred other browser-based blockers changed?

Answer (score 3):

The message normally comes up if some JavaScript files failed to load from the network - why that happened is not something we can tell from here, or from your description.

It could be a temporary network glitch where the files are hosted. Or by your ISP/Network. It may be that you have a blocker setup somewhere, or an anti-virus that did that. Could be one of many things.

That you have posted this question shows that the issue has resolved itself - is this something that you are still experiencing then? If so - specifics like OS, browser (with versions of both) and what extensions/add-ons/plugins you have can help with figuring out the issue.